# Return multiple echo as data for an Ajax Request

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have an Ajax Request which makes a call to "get_suggestion_table.php". This php file's job is to create a HTML table body. The prettiest way to create this table is to use multiple `echo` lines, because I have an foreach of every `<tr></tr>` element. Unfortunately the ajax success function seeems to use only the very first echo of my php file.

Thus I am wondering how I should return my whole table properly. Is the only way returning everything with one echo? (Aka building one big string which includes the whole table I am creating in the php file and then echo this string?).

**My get_suggestion_table.php:**

```
echo "<tbody>";
foreach($suggestedSentences as $suggestion)
{
?>
<tr lang="de" dir="ltr" id="sugg-cont-<?echo $suggestion["sugg_id"];?>">
      <td id="sugg-block-<?echo $suggestion["sugg_id"];?>" <?if($suggestion["sugg_id"] == $sugg_id) echo 'class="mytranslation"';?>>
        <div class="actionbuttons">

         <ul class="actions compact">
               <li id="approve-sugg-<?echo $suggestion["sugg_id"];?>" class="alert-success">
                 <a class="vote up" data-original-title="Approve" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="send_vote(this, '<?echo $suggestion["sugg_id"];?>', 1)">
                <span>Up</span></a>
               </li>
               <li><a class="vote down" data-original-title="Reject" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="send_vote(this, '<?echo $suggestion["sugg_id"];?>', -1)"><span>Down</span></a>
               </li>
             </ul>
        </div>

            <div class="translation suggestions_compact-suggestion_text" lang="de" dir="ltr"><?echo $suggestion["message"];?></div>

      </td>
    </tr>
<?}
echo "</tbody>";
```

**My Ajax Request:**

```
        // Replace suggestiontable
        var get_suggestion_table = $.post( "/assets/get_suggestion_table.php", { suggestion_id:  sugg_id, original_id: unit_id });

        get_suggestion_table.done(function (data) {
            $(replace_node).html(data);
        });
```

Comment: why not return json then append the result in table.

Comment: I don't get your question, you're asking, then provide the answer in the same go? Store the data in a string and echo it after you've got everything you need in it?

Comment: Return your the data needed to build the rows of the table in JSON, then construct the table in jQuery after the request completes.

Comment: Open the AJAX URL in the browser and cross check whether the desired output is present there. You can also check this is browser console. The XHR tab under Network tab will show your AJAX request. Check the response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding a datatype of html:

```
  $.post( "/assets/get_suggestion_table.php", { suggestion_id:  sugg_id, original_id: unit_id },function (data) {
                $(replace_node).html(data);
            },'html');
```

See: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_post.asp

Comment: I tried this and it didnt help - same problem still occurs.

Comment: what is the content of the xhr request,what errors does the console displaY?